# enCapsa -what is it and what is used for?

Tags: data-storage

It may not be a pure programming question but I'm looking for information about enCapsa. Do you know what it is, have you ever used it? I'm reading some papers about it but I can't really see how it works and what it can be used for in an IT company (and this is what i am supposed to find out).

Comment: I don't know but the tagline on their website: "Digital Stem Cells Democratizing Data" gives me a severe case of eye-rolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically enCapsa is a shared data storage system, focused on providing a way for storing any kind of data (even from etherogeneous data sources such as different designed db tables) and consequently obtain it through a sort of human friendly queries, just like on a search engine. They offer the possibility to upload data from everywhere (it's CSV based) and later download to use wherever you need it.
Usages are many, consider it's a centralized DB accessible through web and they say it meets high security standard.
A usefull way to employ this service is to have data stored in there without the need to keep them synchronized across company computers.